# Long solving time for MILP and want to observe how result change with changing variable automatically

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I am trying to solve a MILP problem and it relatively takes so much time to find the optimal solution.(Around an hour or so). I have put a time limit and also change optimality gap(separately) to reduce the amount of time consumed however in that cases I cannot be able to read the relaxed solution values since the problem is not solved.

I need to find out the value of some of the variables in the model with changing some parameters. However, since it takes too much time to solve one problem, it is not efficient to change those parameters after every problem solved.(wake up and change at the middle of my sleep). Is that possible or how to automate the change of some parameters and solve the problem again and again till the whole paramaters range that I defined has solved?(there are multiple parameters I need to change each time, so there are a lot of combinations)

I have a server online 7/24 and after modifying my model with automated version, I want to run it and take all the results later on when they all solved.

Here some part of the log of my problem in case it gives some understanding of problem size

Cutting planes:
  MIR: 4
  StrongCG: 2
  Flow cover: 1

Explored 19098 nodes (6494268 simplex iterations) in 22971.46 seconds
Thread count was 32 (of 160 available processors)

Solution count 10: 2.03677e+07 4.57223e+06 4.01329e+06 ... -0
Pool objective bound 2.03677e+07

Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
Best objective 2.036765174668e+07, best bound 2.036765174668e+07, gap 0.0000%

#

If anyone willing to help, I can also share my model. I am kind of desperate for this model because of long solving time.

Thank you for your time!.

Comment: This is just a programming problem and does not really touch the optimization itself. Just make your code modular, so that you can use an outer loop which prepares the parameters while the inner optimizer build the model. Of course you can do fancy stuff like modifying a problem or multiprocessing, but i would start with the easy approach first (solving time seems to be dominating model-building time). Another remark: this looks like a huge waste of resources (160 processors) and a better model or another solving-approach would be probably better. Maybe even gurobitune to get some opt-params.

Comment: @sascha, thank you for your suggestions. The loop approach is one of the way, which I am going to try out. I was thinking maybe Gurobi has such a function to make sensitivity analysis which I can use it for solving my problem. I used the tuning tool but it does not help much. About the processor power, I don't have access to use all, its shared.

Comment: There is indeed a simple example called [sensitivity,py](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/examples/sensitivity_py.html). Decide yourself if it's something which helps you.